# Weak symbol link on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, linker, linker-errors, weak

Currently I encountered a weak link issue on Mac OS X 10.6.7 with Xcode 4.0.2.

```
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

As the [developer document said](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2064/_index.html), we can use gcc **attribute**((weak_import)) for weak link symbol. However, the following sample code always throw compile error.
As the following:

**weak.c**:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern int SayHello() __attribute__((weak));

int main()
{
    int result;

    if (SayHello!=NULL)
    {
        printf("SayHello is present!\n");
        result=SayHello();
    }
    else
        printf("SayHello is not present!\n");
}
```

The error message is the following:

```
$ gcc weak.c 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_f", referenced from:
      _main in cceOf2wN.o
     (maybe you meant: __dyld_func_lookup)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Even if use option `-undefined dynamic_lookup`, it still throws error at runtime:

```
$ gcc -undefined dynamic_lookup weak.c 
$ ./a.out 
dyld: Symbol not found: _SayHello
  Referenced from: /private/tmp/o/./a.out
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap
```

The `nm -m` message of "a.out" is the following:

```
$ nm -m a.out  | grep Hello

(undefined) external _SayHello (dynamically looked up)
```

Which was expected as the following:

```
(undefined) weak external _SayHello (dynamically looked up)
```

However, when I compile on Ubuntu with gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5, it works as expected:

**weak.c**:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern int SayHello() __attribute__((weak));

int main()
{
    int result;

    if (SayHello!=NULL)
    {
        printf("SayHello is present!\n");
        result=SayHello();
    }
    else
        printf("SayHello is not present!\n");
}
```

```
$ gcc weak.c 
$ ./a.out 
SayHello is not present!
```

The symbol of SayHello in binary is:

```
$ nm a.out | grep Hello
w SayHello
```

> "w" The symbol is a weak symbol that has not been specifically tagged as a weak object symbol.

And I test the old xcode 3.2, it works as expected.

Could anyone help me on this? Was it a bug of ld?

And I found more interested things. When I create a dummy lib to export the SayHello symbol in dynamic lib, it works as expected.

**dummy.c**:

```c
int SayHello() {
    return;
}
```

```
$ gcc -dynamiclib -o libdummy.dylib dummy.c 
$ gcc weak.c libdummy.dylib 
$ ./a.out 
SayHello is present!
```

If the "libdummy.dylib" does not exist:

```
$ rm libdummy.dylib 
$ ./a.out 
SayHello is not present!
```

Works as expected! Weak symbol now in nm message, as expected:

```
$ nm -m a.out | grep Hello

                 (undefined) weak external _SayHello (from libdummy)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know which version of gcc XCode is using? Your answer might lie there...

Comment: Hi Christopher, the version of gcc is i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3). I think it may be a bug of ld in gcc 4.2.1 (build 5666) (dot 3).

Comment: I am experiencing duplicate symbols (typeid(T)) where T is included in several compile units. Only happens in gcc 4.2.1 (build 5666) (dot 3) (XCode 4), not in gcc 4.2.1 (build 5664) (XCode 3). I guess it might have been built on a Monday...

Comment: Maybe it's because you used `__attribute__((weak))` instead of `__attribute__((weak_import))`? I'm looking for a fix for a similar issue.

Comment: Actually, just found what appears to be the issue. "The linker in Xcode < 4.5 forgets to flag weak imports as weak in the DYLD_INFO data." http://glandium.org/blog/?p=2764

Answer (score 0):

This still errors today on GCC 12 and Clang 14 without the `-undefined dynamic_lookup` option:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_SayHello", referenced from:
      _main in weak-518bb6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

But it works correctly with the option set:

```
% gcc-12 -undefined dynamic_lookup  -o weak weak.c && ./weak
ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups
SayHello is not present!
% cc -undefined dynamic_lookup  -o weak weak.c && ./weak
ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups
SayHello is not present!

gcc-12 (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
```

C0deH4cker called out this [link in comments](https://glandium.org/blog/?p=2764). It walks through the problem in detail including some workarounds.